# Eclipse: Auto-generate function comments in C++ source file

Tags: eclipse

A requirement for our C++ coding standards in my current program at work is to place comments before and after functions in the C++ source file (*.cpp) like so:

```
//*******************************************************************
// {AccessLevel} Function: functionName
//*******************************************************************
void ClassName::functionName()
{

} // functionName
```

AccessLevel, as you may assume, would need to be either "Public", "Protected" or "Private".

I'd like for Eclipse to be able to generate these comments before and after every member/static function for me for a class when I do *Right Click* > Source > Implement Method.

If it's not possible to do the AccessLevel, that's not so bad--I could just do `${todo}` in that spot to remind myself to type that part manually. Obviously I'd love for it to be automatic though.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I'm using Eclipse Mars.2

Comment: If Eclipse supports add-ons that would be the way to go.

Comment: Is there not a way to do this in Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do most of these using the Code Templates support.

Look in the Preferences in 'C/C++ > Code Style > Code Templates'. You can set the format of method comments and the method code body there.

See the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_code_templates_pref.htm) for more details.

Comment: Are there variable names I can use to automatically insert the function name and/or the method access level? That's really the root of my question--neither the Eclipse help nor Google has been able to shed any light on that.